# Calling an Async function multiple times

Tags: javascript

I have an Async function

```
function AsyncFunc(args){
    //does some async work here
}
```

then I call this function multiple times in a `for` loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    AsyncFunc(i);
}
```

Does this create multiple copies of the `AsyncFunc`? or are the local variables defined in `AsyncFunc` getting overridden by the subsequent calls?

EDIT

Suppose the `AsyncFunc` does following:

```
function AsyncFunc(args){
    $.get(args.url, function(data){
        args.data = data;
    });
}
```

then I call this function multiple times in a for loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    AsyncFunc(args_object_with_a_different_url);
}
```

Now would `data` go into their corresponding args object? In other words, would the callback attach to the copy of the function in which the ajax request was initiated?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. What is inside your async function (ajax call, webworker, etc.)?

Comment: @DmitryVolokh: The question is already very clear. What is inside the function is not relevant to the understanding of how function calls work (hint: the "multiple copies" phrase clearly indicates that the OP doesn't quite understand how functions work)

Answer (score 1):

The AsynFunc() is placed on the call stack 10 times. Each call contains a localized copy of all variables and functions defined within it. Therefore, they do not share state and "get overriden".

The calls share no state with one another other than any references to objects within the global name space.

**EDIT:**

Example where they would potentially "share":

```
var mySharedVariable = 0;

function AsyncFunc(args) {
    var myLocalVariable = mySharedVariable++;
    console.log(myLocalVariable);
   // do some asynchronous task that i'm too lazy to code for the example as it's not relevant
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    AsyncFunc(i);

console.log(mySharedVariable);
```

As you can see here, if we were to output `mySharedVariable` at the end, it would output 10. However, if we output `myLocalVariable` we would see something akin to 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 since they are local variables and do not share state.

**Edit:**

jQuery async call example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     $.post('someURL', function(response) {
         var myLocalVariable = response.data;
         //the data returned is not a copy, it's an individual instance per call invoked.
         //neither is myLocalVariable shared, each invocation of this callback has it's own memory allocated to store its value
     });
```

**Edit:**
To your most recent question, every `data` object would be unique to each callback after the get request. However, your code doesn't assure me that the `args` variable being passed in is different each time so there is a chance that your implementation could lead to `args.data` being overriden with each callback. So take a look below at another option to ensure you store all of the `data` objects from your callbacks appropriately.

```
var args = [];
function AsyncFunc(args){
    $.get(args.url, function(data){
        args.push(data);
    });
}
//now args will have 10 uniquely different data objects stored inside.
```

Comment: Your function isn't async. Guess, author means smth. different.

Comment: @DmitryVolokh There... now it's async =P

Comment: It has some async code call inside, but isn't "really async". Let it be:)

Comment: @DmitryVolokh But on a more serious note, it is irrelevant whether he is asking about a synchronus or asynchornous task ... this has to do with how memory is allocated and shared on the call stack which is much more about method invocation and language design, not about adding code to make it asynchronous. At the point, it's being pedantic with no real positive gain to answering the OP's question.

Comment: @FeistyMango Thanks for the answer. Suppose the AsyncFunc makes an ajax request and in its success callback, uses the args given to AsyncFunc. Would it also be taken care of? In every AsyncFunc call, I could be making an ajax request to a different endpoint and in the callback, be using the local vars of the AsycFunc copy in which the ajax request was made. Have I confused you?

Comment: @shreyj Every individual call would have its own set of variables as part of the response. None of that would be shared. See my code edit.

Comment: @FeistyMango I am sorry for troubling you, but I am still a bit confused. It would be great if you could go over my edit of question and answer it one more time. It should clear my doubts. Thanks!

Comment: @shreyj Take a look at my edited answer. Do keep in mind that this would be very easy to discover for yourself through a simple test how this would behave. =D